# Convert UTC java.sql.Time to java.time.localtime with correct DST

Tags: java, time, localtime

I have a problem to convert a java.sql.Time (UTC) which is fetched from a database to a java.time.LocalTime (GMT+1 DST). It is always missing the DST hour. So like a Time of 03:00 is only converted to a LocalTime of 04:00 instead of 05:00.

```
//Saved UTC time in DB: 03:00
LocalTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(sqlTime.getTime()), ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));
=> 04:00 //expected 05:00
```

I guess the problem is that java.sql.Time saves the time with a default date of 1970-01-01 and in 1970 there was no DST in Germany. But of course the time should be shown for today and not for 1970.

So how can I get the correct time for this example?

Comment: What value does the method sqlTime.getTime() return? And what value is expected in the LocalTime ?

Comment: Why pick an old-fashioned `java.sql.Time` out of your database? Can’t you get a `LocalTime`? It will still be in UTC, of course, so you will still need a conversion.

Comment: I have to use a framework which unfortunately forces java.sql.Time.

@Ilya
Please look at the code example for the expected and real values. As for sqlTime.getTime() it returns: 10800000

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you are using at least JDBC 4.2, you should be able to retrieve a `LocalTime` from your result set:

```
    LocalTime timeInUtc = yourResultSet.getObject(yourTimeColumn, LocalTime.class);
```

Then there’s no need bother with the outdated and poorly designed `java.sql.Time` class. The time you get will still be in UTC, of course. Here’s how to convert:

```
    LocalTime timeInUtc = LocalTime.of(3, 0);

    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin");
    LocalTime timeInGermany = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .with(timeInUtc)
            .atZoneSameInstant(zone)
            .toLocalTime();

    System.out.println("Zeit heute in Deutschland: " + timeInGermany);
```

When I ran the code today I got the output you expected:

> Zeit heute in Deutschland: 05:00

*Edit:* If there’s no way you can avoid getting a `java.sql.Time`, convert it to `LocalTime` first. Assuming that the `Time` is in UTC and we don’t want to rely on a fragile JVM time zone setting for conversion, you are correct that we need the `getTime` method:

```
    Time sqlTimeInUtc = // Get from database
    LocalTime timeInUtc 
            = LocalTime.MIDNIGHT.plus(sqlTimeInUtc.getTime(), ChronoUnit.MILLIS);
```

If you could rely on the JVM time zone setting also being UTC, the following would be nicer:

```
    LocalTime timeInUtc = sqlTimeInUtc.toLocalTime();
```

In both cases the rest is as above.

In all cases there are some corner cases around the question whether you want “today in UTC” or “today in Europe/Berlin time zone” when you say “the time should be shown for today”. There’s also a corner case if the time is between 2 and 3 AM and today is the last Sunday in March, where the clocks are turned forward from 2 to 3 to initiate summer time (DST) in Germany. Please think these corner cases through and decide what you want.

By the way your diagnosis is completely correct: `Time.getTime` returns the time of day on Jan 1, 1970, so when you feed this into an `Instant`, you are converting the time of day on this date, that is, without summer time.

Comment: Use of `LocalTime` directly requires a driver that actually implements it, and `java.sql.Time.toLocalTime()` will use the default JVM timezone for conversion.

Comment: Argh, @MarkRotteveel, you are correct. This means that if I can’t control the JVM time zone setting — and I can’t, someone else may change it under my feet — then the conversion isn’t reliable.

Comment: It is even worse with the inconsistent way `java.sql.Time` and `java.sql.Timestamp` retrieval is implemented between drivers :|

Comment: I have edited after your comments, @MarkRotteveel (not addressing the retrieval problem, I agree it’s there).

Comment: Yap I am forced to use java.sql.Time. But your workaround does the trick, thanks.

Comment: And also thanks for additional hint about edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it your question is: Given a time in UTC convert it to local time according to the current time offset. This time offset is different depending of whether DST is in effect or not.

A possible approach is to determine the current offset using `TimeZone`:

```
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin");
    int timeZoneOffsetMillis = tz.getOffset(new Date().getTime());
```

Now `timeZoneOffsetMillis` contains the number of milliseconds you have to add to your UTC time to get local time.

You can get a `LocalTime` like this:

```
    LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.ofNanoOfDay((sqlTime.getTime() + timeZoneOffsetMillis) * 1000000L);
```

If your time is only accurate to seconds instead of nanoseconds anyway you might want to use `LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay`.